# only cached version apple-mobile-web-app-capable no page reload

Tags: ios, browser-cache, cache-manifest, iphone-standalone-web-app

I have create a webapp that each time I click on on my ios homepage icon It should update with last data so I need that It reload the page.
This header tag:

```
meta name = "apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content = "yes"
```

works great on my iphone becouse it appears in fullscreen mode.
But if I close in background my app and then I reclick on it the page data isn't refreshed. They are old probably cached data.
How can I use webapp on home page with reload function each time I click on the icon ?

Comment: is there any possibility to reset ios safari webapp cache on each click on the icon to open the page ?  Any idea ??

Comment: I have the same problem... did you found a way to force wabapp update when in fullscreen mode on iOS each time the user clicks on the homescreen icon to open the app ?

Comment: No I haven't found any solution at my problem but I would like to find one